# GridView item height is mismatched with other

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am using a grid view. It shows issue in some devices. One item of the grid view looks shorter in height than others.

[image]

It looks like this in some devices, and in some its fine.

Layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.fueloneApp.MainDriver"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:weightSum="8">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_welcome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridviewMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"></GridView>

</LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:text="For Any Queries Related To Mobile App Click On Service Request"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Item layout

EDIT : Added item layout of the grid view.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/single_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/gris_img"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:layout_height="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/grid_cat"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/divider_color"
            android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I manage the height of each item? What is the solution for this? Please help. thank you...

Comment: make text single line true or fix height of text and image, otherwise if text and image height will increase grid height will be change.

Comment: please share gridview item code

Comment: please also provide code for your gridview item

Comment: Your app looks exactly like one to manage the cash flow of the users. So you are making the app for an existing bank in your part of the world? May I ask how you plan to handle the users credentials? You will needs them to gain access to their accounts on the banks server, won't you?

Comment: I have added item layout please check. @PoovarasanSelvaraj

Answer (score 0):

Gridview is having a tendency to adjust the height of all element with the tallest element in all. Hence this behaviour you are seeing.You can use StaggeredGridView.

Answer (score 0):

i think your grid layout cell  height is ***wrap_content***. this problem same occur with me . change your layout height  **wrap_content** to **match_parent**.

```
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

for better solution please update your grid view item layout cell here.

Comment: Also added item layout please check

Answer (score 0):

Add Textview property :

```
android:maxLines="1"    
android:singleLine="true"
```

if text not visible single line, you need change textview to autosizing-textview

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)